# Facebook PHP SDK LoginURL

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I think I may have an incorrect setting in my app, because if I send the user to the Facebook login url to get permissions it sends them to an app overview page (the one with "go to app" button) and then it sends them to the permissions request page. 
Is there a way to send them directly to the request permissions page and let Facebook deal with whether they're logged in or not??

```
$params = array(
        'scope' => 'manage_pages',
        'redirect_uri' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx/connect/step2.php',
    );
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
```

Comment: To be more specific - i really only want permission for a single page (which I have the id of) and the above code gets it for all pages the user is admin of.